# Scroll bar Explanation

Tags: android, scrollbar

I am creating an application that is adapting well on my phone which is a small 5 Galaxy, and the Galaxy Tab

I'm starting now I'm learning, but now I have a problem.

I work with the application in landscape position.
Imagine a vertical menu located on the right side of the screen.
I made several buttons one after the other.

However the screen does not fit all buttons.

Its cool to create a screen that is small in the case of 5 Galaxy, the menu contains the scroll bar, but the Galaxy Tab No need.
That is, would only need to scroll bar does not fit within the screen.

Like the sites are made, the small screen appears when the scroll bars.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to make my screen has scroll bar when the phone's display is smaller than the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap a layout in a `ScrollView`, which will allow its contents to be scrolled when there is not enough room on the screen to show everything.

Note that putting scrollable things inside other scrollable things usually does not work well, so you cannot put a `ListView`, `MapView`, `WebView`, etc. inside a `ScrollView`.